# Fail to set state REACT/JS: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest

Hello I am trying to loop through a list object and render an object with each entry of the list. However, I kept running into the same error.. I am also wondering how can I see if I a setting the state correctly?

Here is the error that I get

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at Feed.render (bundle.js:11417)
    at finishClassComponent (bundle.js:7881)
    at updateClassComponent (bundle.js:7878)
    at beginWork (bundle.js:7974)
    at performUnitOfWork (bundle.js:8294)
    at workLoop (bundle.js:8318)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (bundle.js:6296)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (bundle.js:6312)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (bundle.js:6251)
    at performWork (bundle.js:8354)
```

Here is my json on API:

```
{
  "next": "", 
  "posts": [
    {
      "postid": 3, 
      "url": "/api/v1/p/3/"
    }, 
    {
      "postid": 2, 
      "url": "/api/v1/p/2/"
    }, 
    {
      "postid": 1, 
      "url": "/api/v1/p/1/"
    }
  ], 
  "url": "/api/v1/p/"
}
```

Here is my obj class:

```
constructor(props) {
    // Initialize mutable state
    super(props);
    this.state = { posts: []};
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    // Call REST API to get number of likes
    fetch(this.props.url, { credentials: 'same-origin' })
    .then((response) => {
      if (!response.ok) throw Error(response.statusText);
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      this.setState({
        posts: data.posts,
      });
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }

  render() {
    const nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    var newData = Array.from(this.state.posts)


    return (
      <ul> 
        {this.state.newData.map((post)=> (
          <li>post</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `this.state.newData.map` don't you mean `newData.map`?

Answer (score 2):

You do not have `newData` stored in your component's state object.

`newData` is scoped locally to the `render()` method.

This should be solved by simply replacing `this.state.newData.map(...)` with `newData.map(...)`